# PHP startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sodium.so'

Tags: php, libsodium, ampps

Currently, I am using AMPPS, and I would like to use AMPPS to install Magento. However, it shows me

`PHP startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sodium.so'`

I found that sodium.so exists in php.ini but not in php74/ext. Then I enabled it and still the same error.
After that, I tried to run

`pecl install -f libsodium`

sodium.so is now existing under php74/ext, but still the same error.

Is there any method to solve this? thanks very much.

Comment: is the lib file location correct? try to check the extension directory which used by php

Comment: Hello, lib file is currently under php74, I think It shd be correct, and extensions file is under lib folder. 

AMPPS/apps/php74/lib/extensions